# jquery UI autocomplete TypeError undefined is not a function

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete

i am trying to add jquery autocomplete to my website(here http://alveline.com/ is tags autocomplete on bottom )
when open web site it give  Uncaught TypeError at the console
although i add jquery reference

what is problem with this code block?

```
 $('#tags').autocomplete({
  source: availableTags
});
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using those specific versions of jQuery & jQuery UI?

Comment: @Johny no ...i try i took it from here:http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/  i just want to add any auto complete to my existing page(alveline.com)

Comment: Well then, add jQuery 2.0.2 https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js and jQuery UI 1.10.3 : http://blog.jqueryui.com/2013/05/jquery-ui-1-10-3/ . I use these 2 versions on my website, autocomplete works great